# How to select multiple bones and set an active bone with Python?

Tags: python

I need to set multiple bones in Blender in a way that's similar to using <kbd>SHIFT + LMB</kbd>. The final bone selected needs to be the active bone. How would I go about doing this in Python?
I've tried a few things, but when I try to use code that requires the active bone be set, I can't get it to work.
I've tried:

```py
import bpy

arm = bpy.data.objects['Armature.001']
arm.select_set(True)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
arm = bpy.data.armatures['Armature.001']
bone = arm.edit_bones['Bone1']
arm.edit_bones.active = bone

arm = bpy.data.objects['Armature.001']
bpy.ops.armature.select_all(action='DESELECT')

bones_to_select = ['Bone1','Bone2']
for bone in arm.data.edit_bones:
    if bone.name in bones_to_select:
        bone.select = True
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`bpy.types.ArmatureEditBones.active`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ArmatureEditBones.html#bpy.types.ArmatureEditBones.active) to set the last selected bone while in edit-mode.

```py
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="DESELECT")
arm = bpy.data.objects["Armature.001"]
arm.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
bpy.ops.armature.select_all(action="DESELECT")

bones_to_select = ["Bone1","Bone2"]

for bone in arm.data.edit_bones:
    if bone.name in bones_to_select:
        bone.select = True
        if bone.name == str(bones_to_select[-1]):
            arm.data.edit_bones.active = bone
```

If you want to state the bone to be last selected as the first string in the `bones_to_select` list, simply replace the `[-1]` index value with `[0]` to use the first index rather than the last index.